# Create a custom auto-increment field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I have this input in the database like `15-001` where `15` is the last two digit of the year (based on datetimeNow) and `001` is my paper number?

Comment: Are you asking for storing field as varchar?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Absolutely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep two fields:
1. ID field - auto incremented on each record inserted
2. Varchar ID field -  computed column

Try creating table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PaperTable
(
    PaperID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
 , PageNumber varchar(100)
  , PaperAlphaID AS Cast(Right(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar(2)) +'-'+ PageNumber
);
```

Result I got when I added "001" and "002" in as my paper number:

```
PaperID   PageNumber  PaperAlphaID
-------   ----------  ------------
  1         001          15-001
  2         002          15-002
```

You may use PaperID if you Paper number to be autogenerated. You will just then need to type cast and concate:

```
PaperAlphaID AS Cast(Right(Year(getDate()),2) as varchar(2)) +'-'+ Cast(PaperID  as varchar(50))
```

Comment: That's good to hear, please mark this answer if your problem is solved with this :)